# product list cannot be cast to iterable type

Tags: java, iterable

product list cannot be cast to iterable type can you tell me how to fix this issue or a better logic to return getProductByName() value as string type please ?

```
public class Products {

    private static Iterable<Products> values() {
        return (Iterable<Products>) new Products(); 
    }
    
    
    private int id;
    private String product;

    private List<Products> p;
    public Products() {
        p = new ArrayList<Products>(6);
        p.add(new Products(0, "Foundation"));
        p.add(new Products(1, "BB Cream"));
        p.add(new Products(2, "Concealer"));
        p.add(new Products(3, "Blush"));
        p.add(new Products(4, "High Lighter"));
        p.add(new Products(5, "Setting Spray/Powder"));
     }
        
     private Products(int id, String product){
        this.id = id;
        this.product = product;
     }
        
     public static Products getProductByName(int id){
        for(Products productName:Products.values()){
            if(productName.getId() == id){
                return productName;
            }
         }   
         return null;
     }

    /* Getters and Setters */    
    }
```

Comment: Consider simply providing a getter for `private List<Product> p;`  PS: Why is your constructor "private"?  How are you planning on creating object instances?

Comment: its public in my code i just wrote it private by mistake

Comment: Why does each Products have a list of Products? I would have made a Product class, and then a separate List<Product> called products.

Comment: ```new Products().p``` is the Iterable you looking for, to values() cast ```(Iterable<Products>) new Products();``` the class should be the list itself (extends) and not have the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code mixes up a number of concepts that are at odds with each other.  You seem to be defining a `Products` class that represents both a single product and a list of products.  Also, it is unclear if you wish to instantiate multiple lists of products, or if you want to have a single list of products by way of static methods.

I would recommend that you define a class named `Product` that represents a single product.  Then, you could either define a second class named `Products` that represents a list of products, or you could add static methods and variables to your `Product` class that allow you to maintain a single list of instances of that class at any one tim

Here is a version of your code that takes the second approach listed above.  The class name is `Product` to represent a single product, and then there are static methods that let you operate on a single list of `Product` objects.  As it is, a list of products is built in, and is created the first time you attempt to access the list of products.  A `setProductList` static method is also provided that would let you create a different list of products and plug that in instead of using the built in list.  The class's constructor was made public to allow for this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Product {

    private static List<Product> productList = null;

    private static List<Product> products() {
        // If no list of products has been set, use the built-in list
        if (productList == null)
            initProductList();
        return productList;
    }

    private static void initProductList() {
        productList = new ArrayList<Product>(6);
        productList.add(new Product(0, "Foundation"));
        productList.add(new Product(1, "BB Cream"));
        productList.add(new Product(2, "Concealer"));
        productList.add(new Product(3, "Blush"));
        productList.add(new Product(4, "High Lighter"));
        productList.add(new Product(5, "Setting Spray/Powder"));
    }

    public static void setProductList(List<Product> productList) {
        Product.productList = productList;
    }

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Product(int id, String product){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = product;
    }

    public static Product getProductById(int id){
        for(Product product: Product.products())
            if(product.id == id)
                return product;
        return null;
    }

    public static String getProductNameById(int id) {
        Product product = getProductById(id);
        if (product == null)
            return null;
        return product.name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Product.getProductNameById(0));
        System.out.println(Product.getProductNameById(2));
        System.out.println(Product.getProductNameById(4));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Foundation
Concealer
High Lighter
```

UPDATE: For the record...If I had it to do over again, I would have chosen to demonstrate the other solution I suggested in the text of my answer.  So much of this class's logic is about managing a list of Product objects, and little of it is about representing each Product. I think it would be better to define two classes, `Product` and `Products`, and put much of this logic in the latter class.  At that point, I'd probably do away with the static aspect all together.